# restrict types of function using C++20 Concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I've created the following class:

```cpp
using namespace std;

typedef std::variant<long, bool> value;

class settings {
public:
    template<class T>
    void set(const string &name, const T &val) noexcept {
        data_[name] = val;
    }

    template<class T>
    [[nodiscard]] inline const T &get_or_default(const string &name, const T &val) noexcept {
        if (data_.contains(name)) {
            if (auto value = get_if<T>(&data_[name]); value) {
                return *value;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

private:
    unordered_map<string, value> data_;
};
```

And this works fine, for example with this usage:

```cpp
    auto config = settings{};
    config.set("foo", 100L);
    config.set("bar", true);
    cout << "foo: " << config.get_or_default("foo", 0L) << endl;
    cout << "bar: " << config.get_or_default("bar", false) << endl;
    cout << "foobar: " << config.get_or_default("foobar", 500L) << endl;
```

output

```
foo: 0
bar: 1
foobar: 500
```

If I try to use the method `set` with something that is not valid for the type `value` (`bool` or `long`):

```cpp
    auto config = settings{};
    config.set("foo", 100.0);
```

We get an error like this:

```
\main.cpp(13): error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
variant(1200): note: could be 'std::variant<long,bool> &std::variant<long,bool>::operator =(std::variant<long,bool> &&)'
variant(1200): note: or       'std::variant<long,bool> &std::variant<long,bool>::operator =(const std::variant<long,bool> &)'
variant(1042): note: or       'std::variant<long,bool> &std::variant<long,bool>::operator =(_Ty &&) noexcept(<expr>)'
main.cpp(12): note: 'std::variant<long,bool> &std::variant<long,bool>::operator =(_Ty &&) noexcept(<expr>)': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
main.cpp(13): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::variant<long,bool>, const T)'
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
main.cpp(32): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void settings::set<double>(const std::string &,const T &) noexcept' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=double
        ]
```

Similar using the method `get_or_default`:

```cpp
    auto config = settings{};
    cout << "foo: " << config.get_or_default("foo", 100) <<endl;
```

We get this error:

```
variant(1302): error C2338: static_assert failed: 'get_if<T>(variant<Types...> *) requires T to occur exactly once in Types. (N4835 [variant.get]/9)'
main.cpp(17): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int *std::get_if<int,long,bool>(std::variant<long,bool> *) noexcept' being compiled
main.cpp(32): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'const T &settings::get_or_default<int>(const std::string &,const T &) noexcept' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
```

These errors are fine, however I like to use `c++ 20` `concepts` to **restrict the types** for the method `set` and `get_or_default` to give a **more simple error** to the user of the class that indicates that the **types valid are only** `bool` and `long`.

Is possible as well to give a specific assertion message for those messages **using only concepts**? Very specifically, **not third parties libraries**.

Comment: Just curios  what was wrong with `void set(const string &name, Value val) noexcept`?

Comment: Note also that this `noexept` for `set` is not a good idea when you add items to  `unordered_map` `std::bad_alloc` can be thrown.

Comment: [OT]: `contains` followed by `operator[]` does 2 lookup, whereas `find` would do only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a declaration:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept is_value=std::is_same_v<T,long> || std::is_same_v<T,bool>;
```

and then make a tiny change to the template:

```
    template<is_value T>
    [[nodiscard]] inline const T &get_or_default(const string &name, const T &val) noexcept {
```

That's it. Make the same change to the other template function.

Comment: Nice, however this work only for those exact types, for example if I add std::string  to value, and add to the concept it will not work with  things that can be converted to string, such a literal "xxx"

Comment: Well, of course. Nothing in C++ happens automatically. Note that literal `"xxx"` has a type of `const char (&)[]`, and blindly forwarding it to `std::get`, with a variant that includes `std::string`, will end in tears. This would involve more than just fiddling with concepts, but also additional template metaprogramming logic. This would be a different question, entirely, to ask.

Comment: You are right, however `set` will work giving `char(&)[]` and having the variant with string, but not with this constrain, but I agree that's another question, so I marked your answer accepted

Comment: @JuanMedina: Note than `bool` is a better match than `std::string` for `const char(&)[N]`.

Answer (score 2):

Not using concept, but you could write your settings in a way that `set`/`get_or_default` are not template:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct settings_base
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<Ts...>> data_;
};

template <typename Base, typename T>
struct settings_node : virtual Base
{
    void set(const std::string& name, const T& value)
    {
        Base::data_[name] = value;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const T &get_or_default(const std::string &name, const T &val) noexcept
    {
        auto it = Base::data_.find(name);
        if (it != Base::data_.end()) {
            if (auto value = std::get_if<T>(&it->second); value) {
                return *value;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
class settings_impl : settings_node<settings_base<Ts...>, Ts>...
{
public:
    using settings_node<settings_base<Ts...>, Ts>::set...;
    using settings_node<settings_base<Ts...>, Ts>::get_or_default...;
// So equivalent to:
// void set(const std::string&, const T1& value);
// ..
// void set(const std::string&, const TN& value);
};
```

And then

```
using settings = settings_impl<bool, long /*std::string*/>;
```

That allows conversion contrary to template way.

Note though that `"xxxx"` (`const char [N]`) would select `bool` overload and not `std::string` one, due to overload rules.

Comment: Really cool code, I realized that nowadays we could use string literals with the sufix s to indicate that are a std::string, "xxxx"s, so that will solve the problem of overloads  when using it

Answer (score 1):

Not a concept, but a different approach:

If you want to limit `get` and `set` to exactly `long` or `bool`, you can have non-template overloads:

```
class settings {
public:
    void set(const std::string &name, const long &val) noexcept {
        set_impl(name, val);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const long &get_or_default(const std::string &name, const long &val) noexcept {
        return get_impl(name, val);
    }

    void set(const std::string &name, const bool &val) noexcept {
        set_impl(name, val);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] const bool &get_or_default(const std::string &name, const bool &val) noexcept {
        return get_impl(name, val);
    }
private:
    template<class T>
    void set_impl(const std::string &name, const T &val) noexcept {
        data_[name] = val;
    }

    template<class T>
    [[nodiscard]] const T &get_impl(const std::string &name, const T &val) noexcept {
        if (data_.contains(name)) {
            if (auto value = get_if<T>(&data_[name])) {
                return *value;
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::string, value> data_;
};
```

Comment: I got same idea than you, but the generic way ;-)

Comment: I love the idea, I'll not mark as accepted since the question was about concepts however this implementation is a different idea but really well done, probably will switch to something like this